# Hide multiple windows by Process

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have a process and I would like to hide the window.

It work great if the process have only one window.

But if there is a prompt dialog or an alert dialog or another sub window, the hide method hide only the main window, not the dialog...

Can you help me to hide all windows of a process please ?

Many Thanks

This is my code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);


    public void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(_processHwnd, SwShow);
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
        {

            if (pr.Id == _process.Id)
            {
                _processHwnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
            }
        }

        ShowWindow(_processHwnd, SwHide);
    }
```

Comment: Update your question tags. For example if this is winforms please add that tag to it.

Comment: @rumplin GUI framework is irrelevant, could easily be console app, question is perfectly tagged fine, could possibly add a windows tag

Comment: @David Heffernan it was an example, nevertheless your right

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a bit more of the Win32 API through P/invoke to obtain the window handles for the other top-level windows.

- Call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the thread ID of the main window.
- Call [`EnumThreadWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495%28VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all the top-level windows of that thread.

It is possible that there are windows associated with a different thread in the process but the probabilities of that are vanishingly small.