# Start a process invisible, and all other child windows remain hidden aswell

Tags: c#, forms, process, hide, hidden

I have used

```
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            psi.Arguments = args;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.ErrorDialog = false;
            psi.FileName = path;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

But I am calling an executable which does 2 things. Firstly it opens new child windows, and they become visible. Second, the application also calls another .exe, which becomes visible (I want this second exe to become invisible)

How do I go about making the exe called completely hidden so no child windows become visible or no exe called by the new exe become visible.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Not sure, but this might be your answer? [Hide multiple windows by Process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267003/hide-multiple-windows-by-process)

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. Did you found a solution by chance?

Comment: Unfortunately I never did get a full working solution. I do vaguely recall using ProcMon to investigate the child process (getting handle information).I think I then wrote code that detects when a child process is open, grabs a handle to its window (forget how i did this part), and then hid it. I cannot locate the source files sorry, but I do recall using this to actually to hide multiple open windows inside a single process. Hope something from here helps